# Place Autocomplete Returns Only Partial Postal Codes in Canada (Forward Sortation Area)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

My team is attempting to use the autocomplete feature of the places Javascript API in order to populate Canadian address fields.  We've noticed that in some instances, the full postal code of a given Canadian address is not returned.

- For working addresses, the place.address_components array contains a type array with one entry: "0":"postal_code".  In this instance, both long_name and short_name contain the full 6 character (plus space) Canadian postal code.
- For non-working addresses, the place.address_components array contains a type array with two entries: "0":"postal_code_prefix", "1":"postal_code", and both long_name and short_name contain only the first 3 characters of what would be the full postal code.

I also notice that for non-working addresses, a simple google search also does not return the full postal code (example shown below).  This leads me to believe that I'm not doing something wrong, but rather, the API doesn't fully support some addresses.  I'm wondering if it has to do with the Canada Post's refusal to put postal codes in the public domain.

Can anyone help enlighten me as to why what I'm describing occurs and whether there's anything I can do to "fix" the issue described?

[image: problem example]

Comment: did you ever figure anything out on this? We're having the same issue with no resolution as of yet.

Comment: yes, it has to do with "Canada Post's refusal to put postal codes in the public domain"  Don't start playing with Postal Codes or you might get sued :D  https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/53ddn3/canada-post-might-own-the-copyright-to-your-postal-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pay much more to get these postal codes. Google is not allowed to provide them to you.

https://www.canadapost.ca/pca/support/webservices